# Removing particular data from file

Tags: linux, bash

I have file which contains list of IPs. Among those IPs I want to remove IPs with 10.0.1.x series.

So to check those IPs I used following command

```
grep -F "10.0.1." IPList.txt
```

However how to remove those IPs from IPList.txt as I have to provide this IPList.txt file as an input to another script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible option is to use `grep -v`, the [GNU Grep 2.23 `man` page](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) says, in part,

> ```
> -v
> --invert-match
>
>     Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.
>     (-v is specified by POSIX.)
> ```

something like

```
grep -v "10.0.1." < IPList.txt > IPList-nolocal.txt
```

which will copy `IPList.txt` to `IPList-nolocal.txt` excluding any lines that match `10.0.1.`

If you want to see the output as you run it, you could use the [`tee` command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_%28command%29) (the linked Wikipedia article begins *normally used to split the output of a program so that it can be both displayed and saved in a file*)

```
grep -v "10.0.1." < IPList.txt | tee IPList-nolocal.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed:

```
sed '/^10\.0\.1\./d' IPList.txt
```

If you want to edit your file "in place" use sed's option `-i`.